# How Acceptability is this Epithet?

Tags: english

I am a non-English native (Arab)

I have constructed the following epithet and want to check whether or not acceptable to English-natives' ear.

I have come across a thin layer of deposits-covered artifact on a riverbed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This site deals with the science that studies language as a phenomenon, so this question is not appropriate here. You should try your question at a site like [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

....of artifacts covered by deposits...

Comment: or perhaps, "an artifact covered by a thin layer of deposits". It's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Mark, I do know the construction of an artifact that covered by a thin layer of deposits on a riverbed. But, is the same construction acceptable to you?. That is, a thin layer of deposit-covered artifact?Thanks again

Comment: @Ayed No, the constructions you propose are not well-formed. "an artifact that covered by a thin layer of deposits on a riverbed", "a thin layer of deposit-covered artifact" and "a thin layer of deposits-covered artifact" are not very acceptable. Pay close attention to articles, plurals, and your use of 'that'. Your proposed "a thin layer of deposits-covered artifact" does not mean the same thing as "an artifact covered in a thin layer of deposits"; it would mean (if anything) "a thin layer of artifact, which was covered in deposits".

Comment: Appreciate your explanation, Mark Beadles.Thanks a lot.